# The woman who is singing a song is my teacher VS The woman is my teacher who is singing a song

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

I want to ask about the positioning of relative clauses:

- *The woman who is singing a song is my teacher.*

VS

- *The woman is my teacher who is singing a song.*

I have two questions about this. First, are both sentences correct grammatically? Second, if so, what are the differences in meaning between them?

I feel that the first one is saying that the woman is my teacher and she is singing a song now. The second one is stating that the woman is my teacher, and the teacher is a singer as well.

Is my understanding correct? Thank you.

Comment: The first one is the natural way of pointing out your teacher to someone who doesn't know her, while she is singing. The second is not very natural. If you mean "The woman is my teacher, and she is also a singer", you should say it like that.

Comment: I agree with Kate, the first one is a natural form of pointing her out. The second form is grammatical but slightly distanced from the person - perhaps the way you would point your teacher out in a photograph 'The woman [in the photograph] is my teacher, who is singing a song [to the class].

Comment: Both are perfectly grammatical, but they have different nuances. The only reason OP's second version sounds "odd" to native speakers is that it requires relatively unusual contexts to be natural (for example, "the woman" is already a "topic" in an ongoing conversation, where people are wondering who she is and what exactly she's doing).

Comment: @FF Some would insist on a comma for the non-defining relative clause in (2).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Would you say that a comma after the "who" is not appropriate in this sentence since "my teacher" is unclear?

Comment: Hello, Ken. << The woman who is singing a song is my teacher. >> uses a defining (specifying) relative clause: << The woman (the one who is singing a song) is my teacher. >> Adding commas makes the relative clause non-defining: << The woman, who is singing a song, is my teacher. >> << The woman is my teacher. She is singing a song. >>

Comment: Hi Edwin. Thank you so much. It so makes sense to me! And, thank you for helping me everyone!